# Display None to classes

Tags: javascript, css

```
 <div id="left-option-navigation">
      <div id="left-option-expand">
       <i onclick="openColl()" class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i>
      </div>

     <div class="left-navigation-option" href=""><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i><span class="left-navigation-option-text">Dashboard</span></div>
     <div class="left-navigation-option" href=""><i class="far fa-file-alt"></i><span class="left-navigation-option-text">Documents</span></div>
     <div class="left-navigation-option" href=""><i class="fas fa-tags"></i><span class="left-navigation-option-text">Products</span></div>
     <div class="left-navigation-option" href=""><i class="fas fa-archive"></i><span class="left-navigation-option-text">Stock</span></div>
     <div class="left-navigation-option" href=""><i class="fas fa-print"></i><span class="left-navigation-option-text">Reporting</span></div>
     <div class="left-navigation-option" href=""><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><span class="left-navigation-option-text">Customers & Suppliers</span></div>
     <div class="left-navigation-option" href=""><i class="fas fa-heart"></i><span class="left-navigation-option-text">Promotions & Actions</span></div>
     <div class="left-navigation-option" href=""><i class="fas fa-key"></i><span class="left-navigation-option-text">Users & Security</span></div>
     <div class="left-navigation-option" href=""><i class="fas fa-wallet"></i><span class="left-navigation-option-text">Payement Types</span></div>
     <div class="left-navigation-option" href=""><i class="fas fa-globe"></i><span class="left-navigation-option-text">Countries</span></div>
     <div class="left-navigation-option" href=""><i class="fas fa-percent"></i><span class="left-navigation-option-text">Tax Rates</span></div>
     <div class="left-navigation-option" href=""><i class="far fa-building"></i><span class="left-navigation-option-text">My Company</span></div>
  </div>

<script>
  function openColl() 
  {
    document.getElementById("left-option-navigation").style.width = "100px";
    
  }
</script>
```

Hey this is my code so i want to know that how can I hide left-navigation-option-text span class when i call openColl() function onclick.By setting the style of the particular class to display none is the solution but how can I trigger this function onclick and apply to this whole class.

Comment: You don’t “apply display: none to a class”, you *apply a class that has display: none to an element*…!

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand you correctly, you want to apply the class to all `left-navigation-option-text` classes at the same time, correct?

You can do it like this:

```
    function openColl() {
    
      let optionText = document.querySelectorAll('.left-navigation-option-text');
    
    optionText.forEach( el => el.classList.toggle('hidden') );
}
```

First, you get all elements with the class name `left-navigation-option-text` and store it in a variable named optionText. Then you loop over all Elements and toggle the class `.hidden` to all off them.

In your css file you create a class `.hidden` and set it to `display:none`.